# Failed Dependency for RPM for osgi(org.eclipse.core.resources) which is not used in Maven Pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rhel7

While building RPM using Maven i am getting

```
38 _[0merror: Failed dependencies:

22:29:39    osgi(org.eclipse.core.resources) is needed by XXX-XXX-XXX-app-XXX.noarch

22:29:39    osgi(org.eclipse.core.runtime) is needed by XXX-XXX-XXX-app-XXX.noarch
22:29:39    osgi(org.eclipse.text) is needed ....
```

Same RPM was building on RHEL6 but above error occurred only on RHEL7.

In App POM there is no Dependency for eclipse.
Any Help will be apreciated

Comment: Please show us the POM file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Practical Solution to Problem.Adding Following tag in POM.Xml help in geting rid of above issue.

```
<autoRequires>false</autoRequires>
```